# How to parse String containing date and timezone to DateTime

Tags: datetime, kotlin, timezone, datetime-parsing

I have such string which can be formatted like this (depending on timezone, so e.g):

> "2018-10-17T15:33:15 UTC"
>
> "2018-10-17T17:03:00 Europe/Praga
>
> "2018-10-18T12:00:00 America/Kentucky/Monticello"

So those strings contains Zone id at the end

How to parse such strings to datetime?

What I was trying:

```
val dateString = "2018-10-18T12:00:00 America/Kentucky/Monticello"

    ISODateTimeFormat
    .dateTimeParser()
    .parseDateTime(dateString)
```

UPDATE:

I've also tried:

```
val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss zzzz")


val parsed: Date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString)
```

But it cannot be parsed

Comment: I recommend you stay away from the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `SimpleDateFormat` will give you nothing you cannot have from java.time and also from Joda-Time (from which I think you took `ISODateTimeFormat`).

Answer (score 4):

You can create an own `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
val date1 = "2018-10-17T15:33:15 UTC"
val date2 = "2018-10-17T17:03:00 Europe/Prague"
val date3 = "2018-10-18T12:00:00 America/Kentucky/Monticello"

//with JDK
val formatter = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .parseCaseSensitive()
    .appendZoneRegionId()
    .toFormatter();
println(ZonedDateTime.parse(date1, formatter))
println(ZonedDateTime.parse(date2, formatter))
println(ZonedDateTime.parse(date3, formatter))

//With Joda Time
val jodaFormatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss ZZZ").toFormatter()
println(jodaFormatter.parseDateTime(date1))
println(jodaFormatter.parseDateTime(date2))
println(jodaFormatter.parseDateTime(date3))
```

This formatter is only able to parse "Europe/Prague", not "Europe/Praga". You can find all supported zone ids here: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-display-all-zoneid-and-its-utc-offset/

Comment: I cannot use DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME, what is an alternative for this?

Comment: Why not? What is your environment? JDK? Libs?

Comment: I am writing Android app - this requires minimum API level 26 which i cannot apply (my minimum is 21)

Comment: Yes I do. I just added an JodaTime example. I'm not an Android developer, so I don't know, if you can use JodaTime.

Comment: Good answer. From the question I see no reason for the optional part since it’s in all the input strings and you couldn’t parse into a `ZonedDateTime` without it. Also `parseCaseSensitive` is the default, so you need not state it explicitly.

Comment: While other Android developers are using Joda-time, there’s no reason to. java.time (including `DateTimeFormatter`, `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and `ZonedDateTime`) has been backported and the backport adapted specifically for Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See also [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). I suggest that the best solution lies here.